# Is there a way to make image fit EmguCV ImageBox control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, emgucv

I'm currently working with WPF EmguCV library running application. I would like to make image editing more appealing thus the image chosen by the user to fit the ImageBox control. It does not need to fit both Width and Height, but rather only in Width.

I am also working on MVVM, but that does not affect this question too much since I could implement it in codebehind too (only view related).

As said before I am working on WPF with C#.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried much. Just of course checked all the parameters where usually you would have "stretch", "fill" and other stuff. Tried to get imagebox width and height and bind that to the image but couldn't because it's emgucv in WPF. The only close way was to do other way around - bind imagebox size to image. That works, but then the imagebox can become really small and zooming becomes aqkward.

Comment: Can you show code of what you have tried, it seems like you need to scale the image according to its width and height ratio.

Comment: I have kind of solved it using ' SizeMode="Zoom" '. It does exactly what I wanted by fitting image to current ImageBox without resizing it. Hope this helps to anyone in need.

Answer (score 0):

EmguCV is not a WPF specific wrapper. In fact if it is anything, it is a WinForms oriented wrapper. At least as far as everything in the Emgu,CV.UI is concerned. So I am guessing you have placed the ImageBox control inside of a WindowsFormsHost control?

I have not had much success with trying WinForms controls in WPF. If @GuessWhat had put his comment as an answer I would have +1. I typically will display Mats or Image on a Canvas object. I find this to be much more reliable.

Doug